# Javascript: Print Y, X times

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, printing, innerhtml

I feel like I'm probably making a fundamental mistake here.  I'm hoping someone can help me.

```
function countdown() {

  x = 5;

  for (i = x; i > 0; i--) {
    document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = (i + " ");
  }

}
```

This is a very small, simple replication of the problem I'm having.

I have a long function.  Within that function is a variable, in this case: X.

I want to insert something into an element(in this case: #display) X amount of times.

I figured the best way to do this would be with a for loop, counting down from X by 1 and each time inserting the string I want.

But when it runs, it only returns 1.  (I would expect it to return "5 4 3 2 1" in this case).

Please can someone explain to me why this doesn't work?  I've been racking my brain over it for hours.

Comment: You probably meant ``innerHTML +=  i + " "``

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are **overwriting** the content of the element in each iteration, by assigning a new value to `innerHTML`. You'd have to append instead:

```
document.getElementById('display').innerHTML += (i + " ");
//                                           ^
```

which is the same as

```
document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = 
    document.getElementById('display').innerHTML + (i + " ");
```

---

And of course it would be much better if you just built the string in the loop and set the content after the loop:

```
var content = '';

for (i = x; i > 0; i--) {
  content += (i + " ");
}

document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = content;
```

This way you avoid searching for the element in the document on every iteration. But `.innerHTML` is only useful to some degree, you should also have a look at DOM manipulation functions (such as [`.appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild)), once you are starting to do more evolved manipulations.